# Tokbox screenshare issue on firefox

Tags: javascript, tokbox, screensharing

I am using session.unpublish(screenPublisher) to stop screen-share and it's working fine on chrome browser but when I stop screen-share with same code on firefox it destroy all stream for current session.

```
    session.unpublish(screenPublisher)
```

Comment: I am not sure why that would happen It works fine for me with eg. opentok-meet.herokuapp.com/testing I can stop publishing the screen without the camera going away. Can you share more code?